# Can someone analyse the word 路 and 㦱？

Tags: characters

I have heard that these 2 word have special meanings since the were made up of smaller words with meanings of itself

Comment: I'm not totally sure what's being asked here.

Comment: @user3306356 I’m fairly sure the OP recently learned that characters contain components that may be characters themselves, and is wondering if combining these components creates special meanings.

Comment: @user20590 you have been misled.

Answer (score 1):

路 (lu4) means "road", and 㦱 means "me/I", which is the variant form of "我" (they both pronounce wo3).

I guess most Chinese people never seen 㦱 in their entire life, including me until a moment ago...

They may present extended meanings when combined with other characters, however when used alone both character are quite common and I can hardly think of any special meanings regarding the structure or component.